# Cross Platform Images Not Showing up on iOS

Tags: maui

In my MAUI RC1 app I add an image to the resources\images folder.  The csproj file is configured to include all files in that folder, and the image's Build Action is set as a MauiImage.  When I run the project on the Android emulator it all works fine.  When I run it on an iOS emulator the image doesn't show up.  It's just a simple .png file.  In reading the docs it sounded like MAUI is supposed to take care of making the images work cross platform.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/images

Is there some way of troubleshooting this, or some other detail that I should be looking at?

Comment: I think there may still be slight discrepancies in the path needed per platform. For now, try some variations. If you have `myimage`, try `myimage.png` or `images/myimage.png`.

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  I have two different pages with two different pngs.  I was using the "image/foo.png" for both, and the image showed up on one page but not the other on iOS.  On the page it wasn't working, I changed the path to just "foo.png" and now it shows on both Android and iOS.  Very confusing.

Comment: This could be a size issue. Not sure why, but a 45 by 45 at 408 bytes png image shows just fine in iOS. A jpg image like 460 by 460 at 40 kilobytes won't. How large is your image?